# Proving by Cauchy's definition $\lim_{x\to -1} x^2+3x-5=-7$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> Prove by Cauchy's definition $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -1} x^2+3x-5=-7$

From definition: $|x+1|<\delta\Rightarrow |x^2+3x+2|<\epsilon \iff |x+1||x+2|<\epsilon$.

Now I'm not really sure how to continue, is it correct that because $|x+1||x+2|<\epsilon$ then $\delta(\delta+1)<\epsilon$? But that doesn't help to find $\delta$...

Comment: No, it is not correct that $|x+1||x+2|<\epsilon$ implies $\delta(\delta+1)<\epsilon$. However, $\delta(\delta+1)<\epsilon$ implies $|x+1||x+2|<\epsilon$, which seems to be what you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Let's suppose that $\delta < 1$.  Then, $|x+1| < 1$, so $0 < x < 2$.  This means that $|x+2| < 4$, so $|x+1||x+2| < 4|x+1|$.  Can you add an additional restriction on $\delta$ so $4|x+1| < \epsilon$?

**Hint 2:** Alternatively, take $\delta < 1$ again.  Then $\delta(\delta+1) < 2\delta$.  What additional restriction can you put on $\delta$ so $2\delta < \epsilon$?

Comment: Are the restrictions: 1. $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/4\}$ or 2. $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/2\}$ ?

Comment: Yup, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

For every $\epsilon > 0$ we need to find $\delta > 0$, such that for all $|x +1| < \delta$, $|x^2 + 3x - 5 + 7| = |x^2 + 3x +2| = |x+1||x+2| < \epsilon$. Doing some calculation we get this inequality $$|x+1||x+2| < \delta |x + 2| \leq \delta|x+1| + \delta.1 < \delta^2 + \delta $$

So if we find $\delta > 0$, such that : $\delta^2 + \delta < \epsilon$, we are done. You can easily see that $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}3\}$. (Note that I chose the $1$ arbitrarily.) If $|x-(-1)|=|x+1|<\delta$, then $$|(x^2+3x-5)-(-7)|=|x^2+3x+2|=|x+2||x+1|<3 \delta=3\cdot\frac{\epsilon}3=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Why is it smaller then $3\delta$?

Comment: As stated, $|x+1|<\delta$. If $\delta=1$ (from the $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}3\}$), then we have $|x+1|<1$, or $-1<x+1<1$. Add $1$ on both sides, and you will get $0<x+2<3$, and so $|x+2|<3$. Put these both together, and you get $|x+2||x+1|<3\delta$.